# Rails 4 devise enable/disable user with jquery ajax checkbox

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, devise

I want to enable/disable user with jquery checkbox but Im getting error like this:

```
POST http://localhost:3000/admin/users/3/toggle 422 (Unprocessable Entity)
```

Here is what I have done so far:

**routes.rb**

```
scope 'admin' do
    resources :users do
      post 'toggle'
    end
  end
```

**users_controller.rb**

```
before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :toggle]

# Enabled/disabled user
  def toggle
    if @user.disable
      @user.update_attributes(:enabled => true)
    else
      @user.update_attributes(:enabled => false)
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :enabled)
    end
```

**User.rb**

```
def disable
    self.enabled = false
  end

  def enable
    self.enabled = true
  end
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
<tr>
  <td>
    <%= link_to user.username, user %>
  </td>
  <td><%= user.email %></td>
  <td>
    <div class="switch switch-square"
      data-on-label="<i class=' fa fa-check'></i>"
      data-off-label="<i class='fa fa-times'></i>">
      <%= check_box_tag 'enabled', user.id , user.enabled, :class => "task-check" %>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
<% end %>
```

and finally my **JS script**:

```
// Checkbox enabled/disabled user
    $(".task-check").bind('change', function(){
      if (this.checked){
        $.ajax({
          url: '/admin/users/' + this.value + '/toggle',
          type: 'POST',
          data: {"enabled": this.checked}
        });
      }
      else {
         alert("no");
      }
    });
```

I can't updated `enabled` field using check box. What do I miss??? thank you

Comment: What's the backtrace of the server ?

Answer (score 0):

Your user.rb enable/disable methods are setting the value '=' instead of checking the value '=='.